# Get command key from SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I wanted to support keyboard for my SpriteKit game, but here's the problem:

We get the command keys from ViewController:

```
- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@" " modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(fire)]];
}
```

But the game logic are all in SKScene, presented from the ViewController... and there are multiple SKScene... how does the scene get the command from ViewController? Or we need to do keyboard polling?

Comment: When you say multiple scenes... I hope you mean you have different classes that could be presented at any time, not multiple scenes displayed at once

Comment: Yes, typically a game has a scene each for title, game play, game over, etc.

Comment: Ok then you want a protocol, when. I get time i will wrote up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send message by `NSNotification`

Add Observer in `SKScene`,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(selectorMethod:)
                                      name: @"NOTIFICATION_NAME"
                                      object:nil];
```

Post Notification form `UIViewController`,

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"Key": @"Value" };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"NOTIFICATION_NAME" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```